# Getting access token issues using PHP client libraries

Tags: access-token, google-my-business-api

I am trying to integrate several Google API calls into a custom Drupal 8 module.

I am basically trying to first get my custom class to get an access token from Google via OAuth before I try do anything else. I am doing this by using a class function with everything simply in one place. The function is as follows:

```
public function testTokenRequest(): void
{
    // Setup Google Client Config within context of initialized class
    $this->googleClient->setClientId($this->googleClientID);
    $this->googleClient->setClientSecret($this->googleClientSecret);
    $this->googleClient->setDeveloperKey($this->googleApiKey);

    // Add Google MyBusiness scope
    $this->googleClient->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage'));

    try {
        $accessToken = $this->googleClient->getAccessToken(); // null returned where breakpoint hit

        $this->googleAccessToken = $accessToken; // Put xdebug breakpoint here
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Currently all I get is a null returned for the `$accessToken = $this->googleClient->getAccessToken();` call.

Unsure where I am going wrong, possibly the AddScopes call because the vendor documentation for the apiclient does this slightly differently, i.e. `$client->addScope(Google_Service_Plus::PLUS_ME);` but I couldn't find the correct class to use for the MyBusinessAPI scope so used the OAuth playground string instead `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage`

I get an OAuth Playground AccessToken returned when I use that but end up with a Permission Denied error instead even though I have the GMB API added to my whitelist under credentials.

Answer (score -1):

Google MyBusiness is Oauth2 based. The access token is not received until the user has approved your app, it is normal that the function returns null if the user has not approved the app yet.

Here is an example on how you create a link where to send the user to start authentication and authorization for your app.

```
        $client = new \Google_Client();
        $client->setAuthConfig(getcwd() . '/../client_secret.apps.googleusercontent.com.json');
        $client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access
        $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
        $client->addScope(
            array(
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage'
            )
        );
        $client->setRedirectUri('http://server.com/code');
        $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Authenticate here : <a href="' .
            $auth_url = filter_var($client->createAuthUrl(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)
            . '">HERE</a></body></html>'
        );
```

The example above assumes your server will also implement a `/code` endpoint where the user is redirected to with the authorization token, then you need to call the api to exchange the token with the access and refresh code.

This document will help you understand further 
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app